# QT6 Android : sharing a file with other apps

Tags: android, email, share, whatsapp, qt6

In a QT6  Android app, I try to share an text file for example with google drive or whatsapp or mail.
At this moment my code opens the possible apps to share, but the file that I want to attach is not send, the message is always empty.

see code below, I think is has something to do with jniDocumentPath.
To test if the file is readable I test it by reading the file.

```
void myapp::shareTextDocument(const QString& documentPath)
{

    qDebug() << documentPath;
    QString m_downloadfilename;
    m_downloadfilename = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation);

//test if file is readable -> result is positive 
    QFile inputFile(documentPath);
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream in(&inputFile);
        while (!in.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = in.readLine();
            qDebug() << line;
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
//text is readable.

  
    QJniObject jniDocumentPath = QJniObject::fromString(documentPath);

    // Create an Intent to share the text document
    QJniObject intent("android/content/Intent",
                             "(Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                             jniDocumentPath.object<jstring>());

    // Set the action and MIME type
    QJniObject action = QJniObject::getStaticObjectField<jstring>(
        "android/content/Intent", "ACTION_SEND");
    QJniObject mimeType = QJniObject::fromString("text/plain");
    intent.callObjectMethod(
        "setAction", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", action.object());
    intent.callObjectMethod(
        "setType", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", mimeType.object());

    // Get the current QtActivity and start the sharing activity
    QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::runOnAndroidMainThread
    ([intent]() {
        QJniObject currentActivity = QtAndroidPrivate::activity();
        QJniObject chooserIntent = QJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
            "android/content/Intent", "createChooser",
            "(Landroid/content/Intent;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Landroid/content/Intent;",
            intent.object(), QJniObject::fromString("Share via").object());
        currentActivity.callMethod<void>(
            "startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V", chooserIntent.object());
    });
}
```

Sharing the file with another app like whatsapp mail or google drive ...
All the apps to share the file are popping up, select is ok, send is ok, but the file is not attached

> After the response. I have changed the code with the fileprovider. But
> still have the same problem. The receiver app (drive, email, whatsapp,
> ...) respond with no data found.  Below the new code

```
//Add in the AndroidManifest file

<application .......

        <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="org.my.myap.authority" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
        </provider>
        
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
//        
        

//Add in the c++ code

void myApp::shareTextDocument(const QString& documentPath)
{
    QJniObject activity = QtAndroidPrivate::activity();
    QJniObject context = QtAndroidPrivate::context();

    QJniEnvironment env;
    QJniObject file = QJniObject::fromString(QDir::toNativeSeparators(documentPath));


    QString providerAuthority = "org.my.myap.authority";
    QJniObject provider = QJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("androidx/core/content/FileProvider",
                                                             "getUriForFile",
                                                             "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;)Landroid/net/Uri;",
                                                             context.object(),
                                                             QJniObject::fromString(providerAuthority).object(),
                                                             file.object<jobject>());

    QJniObject intent("android/content/Intent");
    intent.callObjectMethod("setAction", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", QJniObject::fromString("android.intent.action.SEND").object());
    intent.callObjectMethod("putExtra", "(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/Parcelable;)Landroid/content/Intent;", QJniObject::fromString("android.intent.extra.STREAM").object(), provider.object());
    intent.callObjectMethod("setType", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", QJniObject::fromString("application/octet-stream").object());


    QtAndroidPrivate::startActivity(intent.object(), 0);
}



//Add in the CMakefilelists.txt

if(ANDROID)
    set(ANDROID_XML_FILES android/res/xml/filepaths.xml)
    qt_add_resources(TARGET HyundaiMeteoQML SOURCES ${ANDROID_XML_FILES})
endif()
//

//The filspaths.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
//
```

Comment: `//text is readable` No. Maybe not. You are not stopping if it is not. You blindly continue.

Comment: You use a classic file path in the intent. That will not go. Use FileProvider to serve your file.

Comment: @blackapps //text is readable is onlu for debug.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for the fileprovider sugestion. Try to find out how this work. Never used before.

Comment: I have update the code with this below. But still I have the message "no data available" after selecting the app like "drive" or "mail" or "whatsapp"

Comment: Try to read from the file proviider uri yourself. For the rest i cannot test your code as no coding with QT. Sorry.

Comment: We cannot see the value of the path to your file.